# Cyclic notation and product of transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

$p=(1234)$ means that $p$ sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $1$. But I dont understand why $p$ is also equal to $(12)(13)(14)$. Isn't that imply $p(1)=2=3=4$?

Answer (score 1):

Read the product of [transpositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions) $(12)(13)(14)$ from right to left $$1234\xrightarrow{(1,4)}4231\xrightarrow{(1,3)}3241\xrightarrow{(1,2)}2341$$
that is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4 \\ 2&3&4&1\end{pmatrix}$$
which means $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $1$.

Comment: You beat me to it! (+1)

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the long arrows. Much better!

Comment: You're welcome! :)